# is.na in R Assistance

Tags: r

I have a data set called Bills and a command on R that looks like this:

```
Bills$PaymentDate[is.na(Bills$PaymentDate)] <- Bills$FirstPaymentDate[is.na(Bills$PaymentDate)]-1
```

The result I get is:

> Date of length 0

Can someone help me understand what this means and what the is.na function does?

Comment: Left hand side of `<-` selects all instances of `NA` in the 'PaymentDate' column, and then assigns the right hand side. The right hand side also selects all the `NA` values of the same column and then subtracts 1, which confuses me. The error comes from the assignment not being a date formatted value. Hard to tell with no reproducible example, so this is my best guess so far.

Comment: Bills$PaymentDate[is.na(Bills$PaymentDate)] <- Bills$FirstPaymentDate[is.na(Bills$PaymentDate)]-1

Comment: I made a mistake ^ above is the correct command with the same result : Date of Length = 0

Comment: There are 2 variables, `PaymentDate` and `FirstPaymentDate`, that snippet attempts to fill missing `PaymentDate` values with `FirstPaymentDate -  1`